# Fading color input after color checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a input with a type of color. I want to have it fade out as soon as the user presses ok.

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".square").click(function() {
    $("#rangebar,#colorbar").fadeToggle(250);
  });
  $("#rangebar").mouseup(function() {
    $("#rangebar,#colorbar").fadeOut(250);
  });
  $("#rangebar").mousemove(function() {
    var rangeval = $("#rangebar").val();
    var rangeval = rangeval / 2;
    $(".square").css("border-radius", rangeval);
  });
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin: 40px 0 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#rangebar {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#colorbar {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ---->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <input type="range" name="range" id="rangebar" value="0">
  <input type="color" name="color" id="colorbar">
</section>
```

So how could I have it fade out as soon as I choose a color!

Comment: I modified your code and **kept only the code relevant to your question** as your code was very big and it would probably not get enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily achieve that by using the [**`change`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event, which is triggered for a specific a element when its value changes.

**Code:**

```
/* 'Change' will make the 'colour' input disappear when 'OK' is pressed. */
$("#colorbar").change(function() {
  $(".square").css("backgroundColor", this.value);
  $(this).fadeOut(250);
});
```

---

You can check out **a fully working jsFiddle** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ogqexwta/) or the snippet below ↓

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".square").click(function() {
    $("#rangebar,#colorbar").fadeToggle(250);
  });
  $("#rangebar").mouseup(function() {
    $("#rangebar,#colorbar").fadeOut(250);
  });
  $("#rangebar").mousemove(function() {
    var rangeval = $("#rangebar").val();
    var rangeval = rangeval / 2;
    $(".square").css("border-radius", rangeval);
  });
});

/* My addition */
$("#colorbar").change(function() {
  $(".square").css("backgroundColor", this.value);
  $(this).fadeOut(250);
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin: 40px 0 5px 10px;
}
.square,
#rangebar {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#colorbar {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ---->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <input type="range" name="range" id="rangebar" value="0">
  <input type="color" name="color" id="colorbar">
</section>
```